# Brownie error Cannot load native module 'Crypto.Util._cpuid_c'

Tags: python, brownie

Brownie was working great yesterday.  Today I get this error.  Anyone have a solution?

PS C:\Users\philk\demos\web3_py_simple_storage> brownie --version
INFO: Could not find files for the given pattern(s).
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_3.9.2544.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\runpy.py", line 197, in *run_module_as_main
return *run_code(code, main_globals, None,
File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_3.9.2544.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\runpy.py", line 87, in *run_code
exec(code, run_globals)
File "C:\Users\philk.local\pipx\venvs\eth-brownie\Scripts\brownie.exe_*main**.py", line 4, in 
File "C:\Users\philk.local\pipx\venvs\eth-brownie\lib\site-packages\brownie_*init**.py", line 6, in 
from brownie.project import compile_source, run
File "C:\Users\philk.local\pipx\venvs\eth-brownie\lib\site-packages\brownie\project_*init**.py", line 3, in 
from .main import (  # NOQA 401
File "C:\Users\philk.local\pipx\venvs\eth-brownie\lib\site-packages\brownie\project\main.py", line 45, in 
from brownie.network import web3
File "C:\Users\philk.local\pipx\venvs\eth-brownie\lib\site-packages\brownie\network_*init*_.py", line 4, in 
from .account import Accounts
File "C:\Users\philk.local\pipx\venvs\eth-brownie\lib\site-packages\brownie\network\account.py", line 13, in 
import eth_account
File "C:\Users\philk.local\pipx\venvs\eth-brownie\lib\site-packages\eth_account_*init*_.py", line 1, in 
from eth_account.account import (
File "C:\Users\philk.local\pipx\venvs\eth-brownie\lib\site-packages\eth_account\account.py", line 11, in 
from eth_keyfile import (
File "C:\Users\philk.local\pipx\venvs\eth-brownie\lib\site-packages\eth_keyfile_*init*_.py", line 7, in 
from eth_keyfile.keyfile import (  # noqa: F401
File "C:\Users\philk.local\pipx\venvs\eth-brownie\lib\site-packages\eth_keyfile\keyfile.py", line 6, in 
from Crypto.Cipher import AES
File "C:\Users\philk.local\pipx\venvs\eth-brownie\lib\site-packages\Crypto\Cipher_*init*_.py", line 36, in 
from Crypto.Cipher._mode_gcm import _create_gcm_cipher
File "C:\Users\philk.local\pipx\venvs\eth-brownie\lib\site-packages\Crypto\Cipher_mode_gcm.py", line 51, in 
from Crypto.Util import _cpu_features
File "C:\Users\philk.local\pipx\venvs\eth-brownie\lib\site-packages\Crypto\Util_cpu_features.py", line 34, in 
_raw_cpuid_lib = load_pycryptodome_raw_lib("Crypto.Util._cpuid_c",
File "C:\Users\philk.local\pipx\venvs\eth-brownie\lib\site-packages\Crypto\Util_raw_api.py", line 309, in load_pycryptodome_raw_lib
raise OSError("Cannot load native module '%s': %s" % (name, ", ".join(attempts)))
OSError: Cannot load native module 'Crypto.Util._cpuid_c': Not found '_cpuid_c.cp39-win_amd64.pyd', Not found '_cpuid_c.pyd'

Answer (score -1):

I rebooted but problem still persisted.  I uninstalled brownie and reinstalled
pipx uninstall eth-brownie
pipx install eth-brownie
I was prompted with missing path
C:\Users\username.local\bin"
so i added it
works now.

Comment: You should update the question itself instead of extending it in answer.